# how can i do loop jquery for div pic id and div word id?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class='picture rotate' id="img1">
    <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>   
<div id="fad1" style="display:none;">Cat</div>
```

i'm try to do a loop jquery for div pic id and div word id how can i correct this loop sorry i'm new at jquery and not strong english language.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
   $("#img"+i).hover(function(){
       $("#fad"+i).fadeToggle(500);
   })
}
```

this loop i'm trying to do isn't work.

Comment: you have multiple div?with image?

Comment: No closures in loops!

Comment: I have update my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop just select all the divs that id starts with `img` then we bind the hover event and toggle the next div that is with id starting in `fad`

Try:

```js
  $('div[id^="img"]').hover(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeToggle(500);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='picture rotate' id="img1">
  <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>
<div id="fad1" style="display:none;">Cat</div>

<div class='picture rotate' id="img2">
  <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>
<div id="fad2" style="display:none;">Dog</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class='picture rotate' id="img1">
    <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>   
<div id="fad1" style="display:none;">Cat</div>
<script>
$(".rotate").hover(function(){
var value=$(this).attr("id");
var matches = value.replace( /[^+-\d.]/g, '');
console.log(matches);
console.log(value);
var number = Number(matches[0]);
$("#fad"+number).fadeToggle(500);
});
</script>
```

Demo:http://js.do/code/73877

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to `Attribute` **Starts** With Selector this  **[[id^="img"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**  and  **[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** jquery as like this

```js
  $('div[id^="img"]').hover(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle(500);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='picture rotate' id="img1">
  <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>
<div id="fad1" style="display:none;">Cat</div>

<div class='picture rotate' id="img2">
  <img src="animal/cat.png">
</div>
<div id="fad2" style="display:none;">Dog</div>
```